# Node - ExpressJS: client IP is returning ::ffff:127.0.0.1 on production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, client, ip-address

I'm trying to get the client IP address of the user that came to my site. In my application, I use:

```
... function(req, res) {

   var ip = req.ip;

...}
```

When I check the DB on the live server, I'm seeing ::ffff:127.0.0.1, which is the localhost ip.

I googled for related questions but I'm still unable to find one yet. If any one can elaborate on this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You must be running a proxy locally in front of it, like nginx or something. Check how to configure your proxy to forward the client ip. If you're app is an HTTP server you can use the X-Forwarded-For header (just don't blindly trust the whole header, depending on your proxy's configuration)

Comment: You were right on with the nginx configuration. Thank you.